# how do I get this signature in f#: val sigF : int -> bool -> float -> string

Tags: f#

I am using FSI, how do I go from bool to float?

- have: let sigF 1 = 1=1  gets: val sigF : int -> bool
- need the function that has the signature: val sigF : int -> bool -> float -> string

can you not convert bool to float?
are there any resources on understanding signatures?, I cant find any examples where bool goes to anything else, do i need to understand "currying" better? (I am completely new to functional programming)

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. If it's generic question about currying, then its offtopic for SO

Comment: Agree with Sergey. SO is great, but this isn't the kind of questions we want here. Instead please join us at https://fsharp.slack.com - we have a channel just for beginners, and you'll get all the help you could ever want on F#. Also lots of other interesting channels about F# topics.

Comment: thanks , if you don't know what you don't know... that slack is a very good group of people, a special thanks to (https://fsharp.slack.com/messages/@U42NK7T8C), Alan Ball...   let f 7 true 0.3 = "done";;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this is a puzzle or a challenge, you can assume that `i:int -> b:bool -> f:float -> string` is the same as `int -> bool -> float -> string`. The only difference is that the former also includes names of the parameters of the function - which is just extra information that you can ignore and that does not change the meaning much.

You get the parameter names if you do something like this:

```
> let sigF (i:int) (b:bool) (f:float) = "";;
val sigF : i:int -> b:bool -> f:float -> string
```

The ingineous solution from Michael avoids naming the parameters by instead using patterns (matching against concrete values), which gives you the right signature, but also a plenty of warning because the function will fail if called with any other value as argument:

```
> let sigF 7 true 0.3 = "done";;

warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
  For example, the value '0.0' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
  For example, the value 'false' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
  For example, the value '0' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

val sigF : int -> bool -> float -> string
```

Another solution that gives you the right signature, but without the warnings is to use `_` pattern with a type annotation - this says that you are ignoring the argumnet, but it gives an explicit type to it:

```
> let sigF (_:int) (_:bool) (_:float) = "";;
val sigF : int -> bool -> float -> string
```

Answer (score 2):

let f 7 true 0.3 = "done";;

- 7 true and .03 (all imply function inputs) while after the = is an output

val f : int -> bool -> float -> string

Answer (score 0):

A function having the signature `val sigF : int -> bool -> float -> string` could be for example `let sigF (i:int) (b:bool) (f:float) = ""`. The last in the row of `->` symbols is the output, all others are inputs.

Comment: thanks but the output for that is (> let sigF (i:int) (b:bool) (f:float) = "";;
val sigF : i:int -> b:bool -> f:float -> string), I need them as variables... this is a HW problem that has been giving me trouble.( Q2. For each of the following signatures, create a function that will be inferred to have that signature. Avoid using explicit type annotations!)(6. val sigF = int -> bool -> float -> string)

Comment: Ah, I see what you want now... You want to get rid of the argument names... Try partial application with sprintf. `let sigF = sprintf "%d %b %f"` You'll have to check the format strings for sprintf yourself.

Comment: wait though, its not possible to use sprintf without (using explicit type annotations) though right?, otherwise it just converts it to a string, also I don't think I can do it that way because it is all contained in a return string function which gives parenthesis , output:  val sigF : (int -> bool -> float -> string)

Comment: Not true. Last `->` *does not mean the output*. you can have a function which returns function `float -> string`. E.g. `let sigF (i:int) (b:bool) = fun (f:float) -> f.ToString()` and signature will be same `int -> bool -> float -> string`.

Comment: ```> let test (i:int) (b:bool) = fun (f:float) -> f.ToString();;
val test : i:int -> b:bool -> f:float -> string

> test 1 true 3.4;;
val it : string = "3,4"``` Looks to me as if the output is a string... But of course that explaination is not very sophisticated...